# I am getting this error when I click on edit customer in the admin back-end panel

Tags: admin, customer, php-7, magento2.3.0

I am getting this error when I click on edit customer in the admin back-end panel

[image]

Comment: Seems like you've created attribute for customer.

Comment: Actually, I migrated from Magento 1.9.2.1 to Magento 2.3.0 Customers listing working fine, But whenever I click on  Add New Customer button it gives the above errors.